# Carousel/sidebar list styles in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

There are two list styles that are inactive and produce no result with SwiftUI. Try the `.carousel` and `.sidebar` styles to figure it out.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        .listStyle(.carousel) // Or .sidebar
    }

}
```

Is this due to the beta (bug), or did I missed something ? The List doesn't appear on my iPhone.

Comment: I updated the post. This List is added on my main view.

Comment: @BenjaminPisano There's no need for this to be shown in a view controller - we're on SwiftUI

Comment: @DoesData stop going on about View Controllers, and try reading a simple SwiftUI tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SidebarListStyle` is available on macOS only, as `CarouselListStyle` is only for watchOS.

Here's what sidebar-style list looks like when running on macOS:

Expanded:

[image: Expanded]

Collapsed:

[image: Collapsed]

Here's the code (although I'm not sure that an instance of Range or any other one-dimensional sequence is the right choice for this style):

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List (0..<10) { number in
            self.view(forNumber: number)
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }

    func view(forNumber number: Int) -> some View {
        print("number == \(number)")
        let ret = Text("#\(number)")
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        return ret
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so there is a bug on iOS. I don’t know what should be the correct behavior but I expect both styles to display a standard List on iPhone.

Comment: I don't think it's an iOS bug – these styles are simply not meant for iOS. But it's strange that Xcode did not report using these on the wrong platform as errors.

Comment: Maybe, but this is weird as SwiftUI doesn’t have platform specific UI elements. The only distinction SwiftUI actually does is how to deal with different platform inputs. This is the first UI specific difference I see with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 3):

Like others pointed out, the syntax is changing.

Try it this way:

```
.listStyle(CarouselListStyle())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

It looks like both `.carousel` and `.sidebar` styles are not working / not implemented on iOS.

Here's my demo code:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var alternateStyle = false

    var body: some View {
        var list  =
        AnyView(List(0...100) { item in
            Text("\(item)").tapAction { self.alternateStyle.toggle() }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("A List")))
        if alternateStyle {
            list = AnyView(list.listStyle(.carousel))
        } else {
            list = AnyView(list.listStyle(.default))
        }
        return list
    }

}
```

If you tap on a `Text`, thus swapping the style, you get a blank list.

> SwiftUI is still in beta, hence a lot of components are broken or missing.

Comment: Hmm seems to work OK, but I am personally not keen on all those `AnyView`s